# React playlist player - fetching data and storing the result problem

Tags: reactjs, ajax, fetch, soundcloud

#### What I am trying to achieve

I am building a playlist player widget for my app using [Soundcloud API](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#playing). I am able to fetch the data but I am running into a design/technical issue when I need to implement the play/pause feature for a given track.

The `GET` method returns a JSON track (song) with multiple functions associated, such as `response.play()`, `response.pause()`, etc. Currently, my `onClick()` handle for pausing and playing the song fetches new data for the same track and overrides the current song, which is not what I want. I want to be able to play the song, the pause/play it without restarting.

##### JSFiddle (Wasn't able to implement StackOverflow JS/HTML/CSS snippet widjet)

[[-------- Working JSFiddle here !!---------]](https://jsfiddle.net/ysLtm1cx/)

#### Playlist.tsx

```
const SC = require('soundcloud');

SC.initialize({
  client_id: '1dff55bf515582dc759594dac5ba46e9'
});

const playIcon = 'https://www.pngfind.com/pngs/m/20-201074_play-button-png-image-background-circle-transparent-png.png';
const pauseIcon = 'https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/pause-button-icon-transparent-background-sign-flat-style-204042531.jpg';

async function getJson(trackId) {
  let response = await SC.stream('/tracks/' + trackId);
  return response;
} 

const Playlist = () => {
 const[playState, setPlayState] = React.useState(false);
  
 const handlePlayClick = () => {
   getJson(913128502).then((track) => {
 
     track.setVolume(0.025); //increase if you don't hear background sound
     
     playState ? track.pause() : track.play();
     setPlayState(!playState);
   });
 }
    return (
     <img src={!playState ? playIcon : pauseIcon } 
          onClick={() => { handlePlayClick() } }
          height="100" width="100" >
     </img>
  )
}

export default Playlist;
```

---

#### Things I have tried

I have looked at several SOs posts trying to understand how to store fetched data in a global variable. From my understanding, this can't quite be done because of synchronicity, I can only use the `track` GET response and its associated functions only inside the function

```
getJson(trackId).then((track) => {
   // can only call track.play() or track.pause() locally here ? 
});
```

To bypass this, I tried to do

```
let globalTrack;
getJson(trackId).then((track) => {
   globalTrack = track;
});
globalTrack.play() // undefined error
```

I have further tried to use other tools like `async`/`await` but with no success.
I am at a loss for ideas and lost enough hair over this issue. Does anyone know how I can achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use useEffect() hook to get a track, it will fetch  the track once when the component is first mounted.

https://jsfiddle.net/x7j0qwvh/20/

```
const [track, setTrack] = React.useState(null);

React.useEffect(() => {
  musicFetch(913128502).then((music) => {
    music.setVolume(0.025);
    setTrack(music);
 });
}, [])
```